# Setting Selenium delay between testcases with in Test suite in Robotframework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Have a requirement to set some delay between two test cases in a Robotframework Test suite to avoid cascading failure in one test case to another.

Comment: Not familiar enough with Robotframework to say confidently... but under `*** Settings ***` couldn't you just have a `Test Setup       Sleep 1s` to wait 1 second at the beginning of each test? Or `Test Teardown` to wait after each test for that matter. I'd post as an answer, but I'm not setup to test it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support to add a delay between test cases.

You can accomplish the same effect by calling the [Sleep](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Sleep) keyword as a test setup or test teardown.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley, was trying adding sleep earlier but was looking for any specific builtin keyword support.

Answer (score 2):

I have used test specific actions in 'My Test Setup' keyword and added some test specific keywords to it to setup particular tests. Here is a simplified example:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup        My Suite Setup     # Before the suite is executed (wait 5 secs)
Test Setup         My Test Setup      # Before the current test is executed (wait 1 sec)

*** Test Cases ***
# Tests goes here

*** Keywords ***
My Test Setup
    Sleep    5s

My Suite Setup
    Sleep    1s
```